# Python namespace-subpackage naming convention

Tags: python

According to [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, **although the use of underscores is discouraged**. But [Packaging namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) suggests `mynamespace_subpackage_a` as an alternative to namespace packages. Why they do not follow their own conventions? Is it OK to use underscores in this situation? Any example of packages that use underscores in their name?

Comment: PEP 8 precedes namespace packages by a number of years. I suspect the number of circumstances in which such names are appropriate are small enough to not be worth updating PEP 8 to mention them.

Comment: It is discouraged, not forbidden. So the convention is, in theory, followed.